# App Published under Closed Testing Track but not able to update from Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I have updated one of my android apps in Closed Testing Track, App is also reviewed and approved by Google and also published. There is a message that App is available to Selected Testers. But the testers are not able to update the app through Google Play Store. (Testers also joined for beta version from the provided link).

Please give your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue. How did you solve the problem?

Comment: Same here.any solution?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have 2 different tracks going on. I paused one of them, yet not able to get the update in the play store.

Comment: Are you able to search your app inside playstore. ? For me, i am able to open via the link but not able to search.

Comment: I solved that problem by increasing in Version Code in Gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem by increasing in Version Code in Gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache on the play store app allowed my users to update to the latest version manually.

Without this, they had to wait for auto-update to roll through.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. So I logged out and logged in again to Google PlayStore. then it was showing the app on PlayStore.